# Maintaining a chronometer for multiple fragments in swipe tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, chronometer

I have swipe tabs (6 fragments) for which I try to maintain each a chronometer. The problem is that the onPause is called after the 3rd tab so I have no ways to stop the chrono.

Is there a way to force an onPause after each tab move?

Having a global chrono would be acceptable. I compile the score in the containing activity based on time.

I have thought about:

1. one tab reserved to the chrono. Pros: I can easily add a start/stop/reset button. Cons: No real ways to see the chrono on each tab in real time.
2. having a global chrono in the action bar. Is it possible to add a Chronometer to the action bar? Can I add start/stop buttons? through the settings? Can I retrieve the value from the actionbar?
3. a mix of 1and 2

any more thoughts?

Thanks!